# What's the difference between "int variable = 0;" and "int variable; variable = 0;" in Java class?

Tags: java, variables

I have two versions of codes.

## Version 1

**Launcher.java**

```
class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LuckyNumber game;
        game = new LuckyNumber();

        game.start();
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
class Player {
    int randomNumber = 0;

    public void roll(){
        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }

}
```

**LuckyNumber.java**

```
class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LuckyNumber game;
        game = new LuckyNumber();

        game.start();
    }
}
```

## Version 2

**Launcher.java**

```
class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LuckyNumber game;
        game = new LuckyNumber();

        game.start();
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
class Player {
    int randomNumber;
    randomNumber = 0;

    public void roll(){
        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }

}
```

**LuckyNumber.java**

```
class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LuckyNumber game;
        game = new LuckyNumber();

        game.start();
    }
}
```

The first version of the code compiles without problems, but the second version of the code can not compile, and compiler shows the following errors:

```
.\Player.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
    randomNumber = 0;
                ^
.\Player.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    randomNumber = 0;
    ^
  symbol:   class randomNumber
  location: class Player
2 errors
```

So question is why:

```
int variable;
variable = 0;
```

isn't the same as:

```
int variable = 0;
```

And what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are the same, but only when they are in a method.

In your case, initializating variables without declaring them is invalid outside of a method.

Answer (score 0):

A class in Java can have members.

```
class Player {
    int variable = 0; // this defines a member variable within the class Player
}
```

But you can not put code/expressions in a class declarations body. This can only be in methods or the constructor or during the initializing of variables.

```
int variable;
variable = 0; // this is an expression and should be within the constructor, a method or the initialiser of the variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same untill you write your code outside of method. You can't do like this:

```
class Player {
    int randomNumber;
    randomNumber = 0;
```

It will cause Java syntaxis error. You should read about Java properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a declaration:

```
int variable;
```

and this is a declaration with initialization:

```
int variable = 0;
```

They're both valid at the class level and inside a method.
However for an already declared variable, this:

```
variable = 0;
```

is considered to be executable code and it is valid only inside a method and not at the class level. 
In an IDE like IneliJ, if you write:

```
int variable;
variable = 0;
```

the ide will prompt you to merge the 2 lines to this:

```
int variable = 0;
```

because **it is the same**.